# How to set up a multiproject Grails using Gradle?

Tags: grails, gradle

I am trying to set up a gradle build script for a multiproject grails application.
I have used the [grails-gradle plugin](https://github.com/grails/grails-gradle-plugin) and got it up and running to create a new application.

However, I have some problems when I want to convert an existing grails multiproject application to use gradle.

I have declared all subprojects in my settings.gradle file as follows:

```
include 'core',

        //Plugins
        'plugin1',
        'plugin2'
```

and for each subproject set up its dependencies in their own build.gradle files. e.g. 
plugin1 is dependent on plugin2 so I have declared the following in plugin1's build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
  compile project(':plugin2')
}
```

However, I got the following error when I try to run the *gradle test* command:

UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':plugin1:test'.
Cause: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':plugin1:runtime':
    - unresolved dependency: {}#plugin2;1.5-SNAPSHOT: configuration not found in {}#plugin2;1.5-SNAPSHOT: 'default'. It was required from {}#plugin1;1.5-SNAPSHOT compile

My question is then, How do I set up the subproject dependencies in gradle?

I have declared them in each subprojects *BuildConfig.groovy* as inline dependencies, do I have to declare them in gradle as well?

Comment: The 'grails' plugin is added to the subproject through a `subprojects` closure in the main build file.

Stacktrace can be viewed here: [Stacktrace](http://pastie.org/2196693)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answer my own question If anyone else have the same issue.

I wanted to set the build order for a multiproject grails application (A main application that was dependent on several grails-plugins located in separate folders).

I ended up by declaring a `dependsOn()` in each subproject buildfile.

**Example:**
My main application is dependent on pluginA and pluginB. PluginB is dependent on PluginC

In my root `build.gradle` I declared:

```
dependsOnChildren()
```

and in my root `settings.gradle` I declared:

```
include "pluginA","pluginB","pluginC"
```

In pluginB:s build.gradle file I declared

```
dependsOn(":pluginC")
```

That solved my issue. However it also introduced another issue that the the tests for each plugin were compiled but not executed.

I found a solution for this @ [GRAILS-7296](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7296)

I created a `_Events.groovy` file in the `scripts` folder for each subproject and included:

```
// Override to workaround GRAILS-7296
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.test.support.GrailsTestTypeSupport.metaClass.getSourceDir = { ->
    new File(delegate.buildBinding.grailsSettings.testSourceDir, delegate.relativeSourcePath)
}
```

This solved all my problems and I have now a multiproject-grails application that uses Gradle for the build.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that grails-gradle-plugin doesn't apply `groovy` or `java` plugins, only adds some of the configurations normally added by `java` plugin, namely `compile`, `runtime` and `test`. So there is no `default` configuration that is normally used in cross-project dependencies, nor `archive` configuration that stores artifacts produced by the project.

So it seems that such configuration is not supported by this plugin at the moment. Please also note that generally Grails plugin dependencies are not handled in `build.gradle` either. I think that we can try to fix it, but I realized that I don't fully understand your use case.

I believe that what you want to accomplish now is something equivalent to writing

```
grails.plugin.location.'plugin-tws-communication' = "../plugin-tws-communication"
```

in `BuildConfig.groovy` for the main project, but what's the relation between the plugins from Grails perspective? Is it:

- installation dependency (as in `dependsOn` map in plugin definition)
- build order dependency (so one plugin must be built before the other one? Then we can accomplish it with tasks `dependsOn`)
- compile dependency (so one plugin needs classes from the other to compile)

Comment: Thanks for the response. 
All subprojects have the grails plugin through the `subproject` closure in the main build file. The stacktrace can be found here: [stacktrace](http://pastie.org/2196693)

Comment: @Mathias I've rewritten my answer to include input from your answer

Comment: To clarify my use case, I would say that it is mostly the last relation I have between the plugins (compile dependency), however some plugins have more of a build order dependency.