# Grails dependencies between custom plugin and war file

Tags: grails, plugins, war

I've created a custom Grails plugin, and this plugin needs two other war files to work fine. Can someone tell me how to make that plugin depends on those war files ?
What should I put in the BuildConfig.groovy ?
Thanx all.

Comment: Depends on wars or jars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i get you question, what you need is something to build the app, the plugins and war all together. You could use Maven, Gradle or Gant.

Here is a similar question: [How to set up a multiproject Grails using Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610158/how-to-set-up-a-multiproject-grails-using-gradle)