# Multi-module grails build

Tags: maven, grails, multi-module

I have multiple apps and inline plugins I want to be all next to each other so in IntelliJ I can have them all open at once and edit anything in any of them, refactoring work across all of them, etc.

And I want to have a top level build that will build everything.

I'm using grails 2.2.4 and maven

I looked at [create-multi-project-build](https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/2.2.4/ref/Command%20Line/create-multi-project-build.html) and all manner of links that talked about it but can't get it to work with the inline plugin. When it gets to building the app, for some reason it tries to compile the plugin files and gets lots of compile errors because it is not seeing the plugin's dependencies.

NOTE: Apparently the plugin pom.xml doesn't have the dependencies. So, is there a bug, or am I doing something wrong that would make it not find dependencies?

```
[INFO] --- grails-maven-plugin:2.2.4:maven-compile (default-maven-compile) @ my-app ---

|Loading Grails 2.2.4
|Configuring classpath
|Running pre-compiled script
.
|Environment set to development
......Warning 
|
No plugin [my-plugin-0.1-SNAPSHOT] installed, cannot uninstall
....
|Compiling 132 source files
.Error 
|
Compilation error: startup failed:
Compile error during compilation with javac.
/path/to/file/in/my-plugin:3: package groovyx.net.http does not exist
import groovyx.net.http.AsyncHTTPBuilder;
                       ^
etc. (lots more of the same kind of errors)
```

Is there some way to get this to work? If this maven build is the only option, I'd really like a solution that does not require manually editing the pom's. That way I can just regenerate them whenever I need to update the build.

Are there other straightforward options to creating a multi-module build for this case?

Further detail:
Running grails test-app in the plugin or in the app work successfully.

Comment: I think that you can use Gradle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610158/how-to-set-up-a-multiproject-grails-using-gradle

Comment: ttt, did you find a good solution for this issue?